# date column empty in extjs 4 grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a datecolumn in my grid. Is there a way to ensure than that the date value will not be empty.

ie see the below image. This field has a date. But when i double click to edit the value is cleared.

[image]

```
{
    id: 'Created',
    text: "Created",
    dataIndex: 'Created',
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    format: 'd/m/Y H:m',
    width: 150,
    sortable: true,
    field: {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        allowBlank: true,
        format: 'd/m/Y H:m'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last 'm' in the dateformat refers to the month, it should be `'d/m/Y H:i'` if you want it to refer to the minutes. Also by the looks of your screenshot, it should have month first `'m/d/Y/ H:i'` unless there is something going on on the 2nd of every month in the future, e.g. your "02/08/2012" is *supposed* to be 2 August 2012. To answer your question though:

Make sure you have the format defined in the model (it looks like you may because it renders ok without the editor), can't tell though:

```
// your column model
Ext.define('Whatever', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        ...,
        {name: 'Created', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'm/d/Y H:i'},
        ...,
    ]
});
```

Column config should be something like this (use `editor` config - not field):

```
columns: [..., {
    // date column
    id: 'Created',
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    header: 'Created',
    dataIndex: 'Created',
    width: 150,
    sortable: true,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        allowBlank: true,
        format: 'm/d/Y H:i',
    }, ...
}]
```